# Please help identify this vintage component

Tags: identification, electrical, vintage

I got this item in a bidding lot and have been trying to figure out what it is ever since. 
The nearest I can tell it is either an electro shock therapy device or perhaps a remote detonator. It has brushes and a fluted cylinder. Very heavy cylinder with a handle to spin the cylinder and an electrical contact is what it appears to be On one side. Has a ground lug.

I haven't tested for current since one of the brushes is missing.

Has anyone seen One of these and know what it is?[image: generator for something]

Comment: More perspectives and measurements could help

Comment: Is the glass globe in the background a part of it? It looks as though the drum is turned by the knob and that the contact might make and break at a frequency proportional to the speed of rotation. Could that be true? Some sort of manual frequency generator? But why the width of the drum then?

Comment: Yeah more pictures would help, as well as any descriptions of the materials of the parts.  What is that cylinder?  Rusted steel?  You may be able to disassemble it without damaging it to take pictures.  Don't be afraid to go on reddit to post on r/whatisthisthing/ as they have a much much larger community.  If you figure out what it is before anyone else does, please come back and post the answer to your question.

Comment: If it is custom made instead of mass produced, we can only guess as to what it is and does. I have been in vintage museums and not seen anything like that.